# Which container service to choose in Azure

Tags: azure, docker, containers

We are planning to use docker for our new project and I'm kinda not sure what are the differences in various services azure provides you. Especially the following:

Container instances

Service Fabric cluster

App Services

These are the options when creating new container. Can someone please explain what are the differences? Which to choose and when?

Comment: Is it just the one container, or do you plan on having multiple? Is it something that needs to run continuously or is it something that will get a request and do some processing from time to time?

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a chance to look out the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/compute-decision-tree) ?

Understand the basic features
If you're not familiar with the Azure service selected in the previous step, read the overview documentation to understand the basics of the service.

- App Service. A managed service for hosting web apps, mobile app back ends, RESTful APIs, or automated business processes.
- Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS). A managed Kubernetes service for running containerized applications.
- Batch. A managed service for running large-scale parallel and high-performance computing (HPC) applications
- Container Instances. The fastest and simplest way to run a container in Azure, without having to provision any virtual machines and without having to adopt a higher-level service.
- Functions. A managed FaaS service.
- Service Fabric. A distributed systems platform that can run in many environments, including Azure or on premises.
- Virtual machines. Deploy and manage VMs inside an Azure virtual network.

[image]

Comment: Just curious.. why isn't the docker mentioned in the flow ??

Comment: docker is just a way to containerize your solution, it will be applicable wherever you see the word container, it can be with service fabric, container instance or even aks

Comment: did it help to understand more?